# Foolishly left old beta on my iPhone that has now expired, is my only option to restore and lose everything?

Tags: iphone, restore, ios, beta-seed-program

I installed an iOS 8 beta on a test iPhone I have back in the summer, and forgot to keep it updated with more recent betas, and now it's not allowing me to get into it due to the beta being expired.

Is my only option to be able to use it again to restore it from scratch and lose everything? Or is there some way to update it to the actual released version of iOS 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply download the IPSW of the final build of iOS 8.1 from developer.apple.com, connect your device to iTunes, alt-click the Update button and select your IPSW.

No data will be lost and your device will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you will have to restore the device, which will wipe the contents of the device.

However, if you have a back up of the device's contents (either on iCloud or stored on your computer), it is a simple option in the device re-setup process to restore your device (now with the latest version of iOS) to this backup, thus allowing you to regain access to your data.